# desplegar datalist automaticamente

Tags: jquery, lista, dropdownlist

Como puedo desplegar  esta lista mediante jquery?

```html
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Hola Lorenzo al parecer llevas tiempo en la plataforma y de mi parte no me gustaría calificarte mal, pero muchos podrían hacerlo ya que es lo que se debe, te dejo aquí [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), por los momentos tu pregunta es pobre y carece de contenido, te invito a modificara y con gusto estaré tambien para responder, un saludo!

Comment: Gracias por tus consejos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, es un poco complicado ya que un input list no esta diseñado para hacer de dropdown, ya que solo es un input de auto completado y no es necesario este evento, mas sin embargo podrías utilizar la siguiente lógica:

Dentro de un `$(document).ready()` puedes hacer que este campo se seleccione automáticamente de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

     setTimeout(function(){
     
      $("#list").focus();
 
      $("#browsers").mousedown();
     
     }, 1000);

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="list" list="browsers">

    <datalist id="browsers">
      <option value="Internet Explorer">
      <option value="Firefox">
      <option value="Chrome">
      <option value="Opera">
      <option value="Safari">
    </datalist>
```

Esto crea un evento click en el input al cargar la pagina y así se selecciona automáticamente, pero este sigue siendo seleccionado para desplegarse, sin embargo espero que te haya sido de ayuda!

Comment: Hola, seguro que estoy haciendo algo mal, pero a mi no me ha funcionado. Lo podrías poner en un ejemplo verificable? Gracias

Comment: Que navegador estas usando?

Comment: En chrome  `69.0.3497.100` no funciona

Comment: Efectivamente:

A partir de la versión 53+, Google Chrome no realizará una acción predeterminada para eventos no confiables. Tales como eventos creados o modificados por script, o enviados a través del método dispatchEvent. 

https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5718803933560832 https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6461137440735232

Comment: Mas allá de esto, creo que no existe una solución factible para "programaticamente" desplegar un elemento list o un select puesto a que no es visto como algo necesario, como alternativa, puedes crear tu propio menú desplegable con un input y unos cuantos elementos de lista, de tal manera que los programes para que funcione como un list, efectuando autocompletado y de mas, si te interesa esto, siempre puedes comentarlo y tratare de publicar una respuesta para ello. Para ayudarte Lorenzo, saludos.